# How to post a formatted data from MongoDB to a HTML page?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

I am looking at posting a nicely formatted data on to a webpage using HTML. I wrote a code in python using Flask and Mongodb as my db.

```
@app.route('/')
def Results():
    try:
        Project_List_Col = db.ppm_master_db_collection.find({}, 
   {"_id":0})
    return render_template('Results.html',tasks=Project_List_Col)
except Exception as e:
    return dumps({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   app.run(debug = True)
```

However, the data is printed like a JSON format. I want it to be formatted in a tabular format.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
   <body>
     {% for task_id in tasks %}
        <h3>{{task_id}}</h3>
     {% endfor %}
   </body>
</html>
```

Currently the output is something similar to:

```
[{u'total': 9942806, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c1'}},
 {u'total': 10173832, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c2'}},
 {u'total': 9567489, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c3'}}]
```

However, I need it to be like:

```
Day     C1    C2    C3    C4
1      123   125  122    254 
2       123   125  122    254
3       123   125  122    254
```

I need help on how can I have a readable and better UI output.

Answer (score 0):

The below HTML Code resolved the issue:

```
<html>
   <body>
         {% for task_id in tasks %}
            <h3>{{task_id}}:{{tasks[task_id]}}</h3>
         {% endfor %}
   </body>
</html>
```

On further research I understand the Task_id basically a dictionary.